# Handling Cookies in Flutter

Tags: android, facebook, flutter, okhttp, cookiejar

I want to make a new flutter application, I'm using the Facebook Login SDK (for flutter). The login was succefully implemented and I am able to get the accesstoken and the UID of the connected user.

My problem is, when the user logs in, I want to keep these cookies to use it with an HTTP request. I was able to make with native android (with the `cookiejar` and `OKHTTP` library). I'm wondering if it is still possible with Flutter.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Cookie class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/Cookie-class.html)?

Comment: @SnakeyHips how could I use it to get the webview Cookie ?

Answer (score -2):

Check out [requests](https://github.com/jossef/requests), a flutter library to help with modern RESTful http requests (basic cookies support and json)

- as of now, it uses [shared_preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) which is not the best practice (security-wise) to store sensitive data (session-ids etc) [Issue #1](https://github.com/jossef/requests/issues/1)

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  requests: ^1.0.0
```

Usage:

```
import 'package:requests/requests.dart';

// ...

// this will persist cookies
await Requests.post("https://example.com/api/v1/login", body: {"username":"...", "password":"..."} ); 

// this will re-use the persisted cookies
dynamic data = await Requests.get("https://example.com/api/v1/stuff", json: true);
```